# Entity Framework one-to-zero-or-one foreign key association

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

I am in the process of changing the back-end of an existing application to use Entity Framework Code First. I've used the built-in tool in Visual Studio 2015 to generate POCO classes based on my existing database. This worked perfectly for the most part, except for two classes, with a one-to-zero-or-one relationship. These are my (simplified) classes:

```
public class Login
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TeamMemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual TeamMember TeamMember { get; set; }
}

public class TeamMember
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Login Login { get; set; }
}
```

With the following configuration:

```
public class LoginTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Login>
{
    public LoginTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasRequired(e => e.TeamMember)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Login);

        this.Property(e => e.TeamMemberId)
            .HasColumnName("TeamMember_Id");
    }
}
```

This results in the following migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Logins",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            TeamMember_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.TeamMembers", t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Id);
```

For some reason EF creates a foreign key on `[Logins].[Id]` instead of `[Logins].[TeamMember_Id]`. I've already tried decorating my navigation property with a `ForeignKey` attribute, but this did not work. Is there a way to get it to create a foreign key on `[Logins].[TeamMember_Id]` instead?

Comment: OMG. I'm having this exact problem. Have you had any luck finding it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating one-to-many relationship, with a `[NotMapped]` property for Login.

My classes:

```
public class Login
{
    public int TeamMemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual TeamMember TeamMember { get; set; }
}

public class TeamMember
{
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Login Login
    {
        get { return Logins.FirstOrDefault(); }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}
```

With the following configuration:

```
public class LoginTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Login>
{
    public LoginTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.Property(e => e.TeamMemberId)
            .HasColumnName("TeamMember_Id");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can write your code first like this. Entity Framework will generate foreign key `TeamMemberId` automatically for you. For more information: [Entity Framework Tutorial -
 Code First Conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx)

```
public class Login
{
   public int Id { get; set; } //foreign key declaration
   public int TeamMemberId { get; set; }
   public  TeamMember TeamMember { get; set; }
}

public class TeamMember
{
   public int TeamMemberId { get; set; }
   public Ilist<Login> Login { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware that Entity Framework will generate the property `TeamMember_Id` automatically. But I need it to be explicitly defined, since the code references this property. Also, it should be a one-to-zero-or-one relationship, not a one-to-many, like your code suggests.