# Entity Framework one to zero one association reference key mapping

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I have Customer and Address classes as you see in the picture below. 
[image]

I am trying to make one to zero one association between those two tables. Entity Framework makes it work perfectly, but it won't use my property as a reference key. In this case it is "ShippingAddressId". Instead it is generating ShippingAddress_Id. I don't have problem with that either. My issues is EF is not letting me map to either property. I use the reference key property in my business logic. is there way to map the foreign key field to a property in the case of one to one? I looked and find that you can do it if your relationship is one to many by saying HasForeignKey(x=>x.ForeignKeyProperty). Why EF doesn't allow the same thing with one to zero one? Is there any other way to do it?

Someone asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868054/entity-framework-one-to-zero-or-one-foreign-key-association), but it doesn't answer what exactly I want.

Comment: one to zero one is 1 to 1 relation?  Can you explain why you have field ShippingAddress when you have ShippingAddressID? And if you don't find right answer, you can delete filed Address2 in table Address and make one to many relationship between those two tables. That's relationship for this example is better then one to one.

Comment: @MiOnIs I am not sure if you understand how associations work. There is a big difference between 1 to 1 and 1 to 0..1. And I don't understand why you think that if I have ShippingAddressId then I don't need the ShippingAddress.

Comment: And i don't understand why you need ShippingAddress and ShippingAddressId, because you can get all information from ShippingAddressId what you need. I don't know answer on your question so i don't want to waste your time.

Comment: Only EF team can tell *why*, but that's the reality and you have to accept the fact it's not supported. Take a look at the question marked as duplicate for a workaround with `MapKey` and implicit (shadow) FK property.

Comment: @IvanStoev I was using the PK as FK until now, but now I have a scenario that using the PK as FK doesn't work. For example: I have a customer and it needs to make two one to one references to address table. BillingAddress and ShippingAddress. How do you deal with this?

Comment: By using the other approach from my answer. So in `Customer` class you'll remove `public int ShippingAddressId { get; set; }` and use  `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasRequired(e => e.ShippingAddress).WithOptional(e => e.Customer).Map(m => m.MapKey("ShippingAddressId"));`

Comment: You can also take a look at [Associations in EF Code First: Part 5 – One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations) for alternative approach using `WithMany` with Address examples similar to yours.